# User PHP to add text if user uploaded any files to multi file uploader

Tags: php

Can someone help me add a PHP IF command for multi file upload fields so that I can add a header text if user uploaded files? I have 10 multi file upload fields that I am using as part of Gravity Forms. I am outputting this to a pdf and just cant figure this out.

Here is my code that posts the images to the pdf.

```
if ( is_array( $form_data['field']['170_path'] ) ) {  
     $allowed_extensions = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif' );


/* Not sure how to write the if command */
/* I tried the code below but it doesnt work*/
if(empty( $form_data['field']['170_path'] ) && empty( $path ) ) {
    echo "there is no file uploaded";
exit;
} else {
echo "there is file";
}
/* --------------------- */

/* The code below is working. I just need help with the section above */

foreach ( $form_data['field']['170_path'] as $path ) { 
     $extension = strtolower( pathinfo( $path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

     if( in_array( $extension, $allowed_extensions ) && is_file( $path ) ) { 
          echo '<img src="'. $path .'" />';
                   }


}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'header'? You mean, like a watermark? Or expand the image canvas size and insert some text in the image above the original image? Or just insert text in the PDF file above the image? In any case, you need to show us what you have tried.

Comment: I simply mean that i need to add text above the posted images on the pdf. For instance,  echo '<h3 style="text-align: center;">-Section Image Gallery -</h3>';   Also, please note that I do not want to add text above each image. I just need to add it above the group of images (like a header).

Comment: How are you creating the PDF because it looks like you're just outputting HTML above. Can you not just put `echo '<h3 style="text-align: center;">-Section Image Gallery -</h3>';` where you have `"there is file"`?

Comment: I am using gravitypdf but i dont have a problem with the html formating. The important issue is creating the proper way of integrating the php if command into the code.

Comment: You missed the second part of my previous comment. You already have the `if/else` statement in your code. Just put it in there.

Comment: That is my problem. That code is not working. I’m not sure why.

Comment: Did you check your web server's log files? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No. Just checking the output as seen in the resulting pdf.  I know there is an issue with the code and just figured someone might have a quick easy example for me to test.